# Computing the percentage change in R with NA or 0 as values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataFrame made up df as follows:

```
Name      values   percertage_change
N1        2.000                          
N1        2.075     0.0375
N1        2.150     0.0361
N1        2.225     0.0348
N1        2.300     0.0337
N2         NA         
N2         3          ?
N2         4        0.333
N2         0        1.000
N2         3          ?
```

The formula to compute the percentage change is given by:

```
Percentage_change[i+1]=(values[i+1]-values[i])/value[i]
```

How do I compute in R when my values[i] is NA or 0?

Comment: It is, by definition, impossible to calculate a percentage change from an NA record. What do you have in mind? You could set it to NA too, to a given value (say zero, for instance) or use the last existing record as base. You'll need to define it first, though

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("zoo")
library(zoo)

df <- zoo(df)
df$percentage_change <- df$values / lag(df$values, -1, na.pad = TRUE) - 1
```

This should pad the first row with `NA` and then it should return `NA` where appropriate.

Comment: It should work with negative numbers; however, in my opinion, expressing a percentage change with negative quantities is flaky at best and can lead to poor decision-making at its worse -- especially when crossing the zero-line.

Comment: But we can have a value going from 1 to -1. Does it also take into accounts the 0? for example, we can have  a value going from 0 to 3. Those are all possible as we do not know the complete nature of our data set. But those two scenarios are possible

Comment: It will calculate *something* -- whether that *something* is correct or incorrect is up for interpretation. Just try some sample data: `x <- zoo(-5:5); x / lag(x, -1, na.pad = TRUE) - 1;`